# Text input - restrict no more than 5 decimals and more than number 100

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to create a text input that restricts user from entering more than five decimals and allowing to enter only numbers through 0 - 100. For example:

`100 - valid`

`29.39499 - valid`

`9.999 - valid`

`0 - valid`

`12.0828282 - invalid`

`101 - invalid`

`0.0123 - valid`

`.111 - valid`

How would I approach this?

```
'decimalInput': new FormControl({value: ''}, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d*\.?\d*$/), Validators.max(100), Validators.min(0)])
```

```
    setDecimals(event){
/*    My attempt to get less than 5 decimals and less than number 100:
       let finalValue = event.target.value + event.key;
        let countDecimals = function (value) {
            if(Math.floor(value) === value) return 0;
            return value.toString().split(".")[1].length || 0;
        }

        if(parseFloat(finalValue) >= 100 || countDecimals(parseFloat(finalValue)) > 5){
            return false;
        }*/

        let charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.key;
        if (charCode == 46) {
            if (event.target.value.indexOf('.') === -1) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if (charCode > 31 &&
                (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

```
<input type="text" pInputText formControlName="decimalInput" maxlength="8 (keypress)="setDecimals($event)">
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a regex which will allow for a whole number of 100 with or without trailing decimal and zeros or a number under 100 with up to five decimal places:

```
/(^100([.]0{1,5})?)$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{1,5})?)$/
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, is there a way I can restrict the user from entering the number (like returning false in keypress) rather than form validation with regex?

Comment: did you mean something like this: let finalValue = event.target.value + event.key? I am adding a new character each time a key is pressed.

And I am getting a reference error when I try using onkeydown, would you happen to know why?

Comment: @Pray I just noticed you were using `angular` perhaps you should just stick with what you are using, just apply the regex test in your function.